# How to fix NoReverseMatch error in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a web app to manage students. When creating/ updating students a 
"NoReverseMatch" error is thrown. I'm new to django but I cannot figure out why it's throwing the error when the exact same pattern name is present in the urls files. The delete redirect does not work either.

urls.py:

```
path('Student/', views.StudentListView.as_view(), name='Students'),
path('Student/<int:pk>', views.StudentDetailView.as_view(), name='Student-detail'),
path('Student/create/', views.StudentCreate.as_view(), name='Student_create'),
path('Student/<int:pk>/update/', views.StudentUpdate.as_view(), name='Student_update'),
path('Student/<int:pk>/delete/', views.StudentDelete.as_view(), name='Student_delete'),
```

views.py:

```
class StudentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Student

class StudentListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'main/student_list.html'

class StudentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Student
    fields = '__all__'

class StudentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Student
    fields = ['student_name']

class StudentDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Student
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Students')
```

student_form.html:

```
{%block content%}
<body>
Add new student:
 <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
{%endblock%}
```

Instead of redirecting back to the student detail page I get the following error:

NoReverseMatch at /Student/1/update/

Reverse for 'Student-detail' not found. 'Student-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably you are missing the trailing `/` here: `'Student/<int:pk>'`

Comment: Nope, I added the trailing `/` and it didn't fix the error.

Comment: Or missing `success_url` on `StudentUpdate`?

Comment: How would I add a `success_url` for `StudentUpdate`?

Comment: Override `get_success_url` should do it, and you can pass in the `pk` from `self`. Like: `def get_success_url(self): return reverse('Student-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})`. Or something along those lines.

Comment: If you are using a namespace in your `urls.py`, e.g. `app_name='student'`, then you need to include it when you reverse the URL, e.g. `reverse_lazy('student:Students')` and `{% url 'student:Students' %}`.

Comment: @jhrr great! it worked thanks!

Comment: @Alasdair that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @Egor.L Nice one!